# Is Kissmetrics using ETags for tracking (again)?

Tags: privacy, http, user-tracking, tracking

Ayenson et al. reported in their paper *[Flash Cookies and Privacy II: Now with HTML5 and ETag Respawning][1]* years ago that Kissmetrics used ETags to identify clients.

When looking at a site which uses Kissmetrics, for example http://www.up.edu.br/, I can see the `ETag` element in the response header when loading the Kissmetrics' tracking library.

[image: Kissmetrics ETag]

According to their [privacy policy][4], they do not use ETags for tracking purposes:

> Kissmetrics’ Use of Cookies and Web Beacons
>
> Cookies. Kissmetrics uses cookies (small text files that Kissmetrics
>   stores locally on your computer) on our Client’s websites for one or
>   more of the following purposes: to help identify unique visitors
>   and/or devices; assess usage patterns and perform traffic analysis;
>   identify visitor preferences; conduct A/B testing; diagnose problems
>   with our servers, and otherwise administer the Kissmetrics Service.
>   Kissmetrics does not use methods such as browser cache, Flash cookies,
>   or eTags, for acquiring or storing information about end users web
>   browsing activity on Client websites or otherwise.

However, I do see the exact same identifier when browsing in private mode.

So, are they using ETags *again*?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! There seem to be a link missing to the privacy policy. Not a big deal, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, are they using ETags again?

The `Etag` HTTP header is used for caching in HTTP, i.e. the browsers includes the given tag in the `If-None-Match` header of the HTTP request so that it only gets the response body if it has been changed compared to the previous access. `Etag` can be used for tracking but most uses of `Etag` care only about caching and not tracking. Thus just the existence of this header in the HTTP response is no indicator that it is used for tracking.